# Substitute string sequences for BLOSUM62 values in R

Tags: r, matrix, bioconductor

I have a df with several peptide sequences. For each sequence, I need to replace each AA for the BLOSUM62 values stored in another matrix.

```
|Sequences|
|:--------|
|KIFREIIHL|
|LALTYRGLI|
|DIKGLIVYR|
|...      |

**BLOSUM62 matrix**

       A       R       N       D       C       Q       E       G       H       I       L       K       M       F       P       S       T       W       Y       V
A 0.29015 0.03104 0.02564 0.02969 0.02159 0.02564 0.04049 0.07827 0.01484 0.04318 0.05938 0.04453 0.01754 0.02159 0.02969 0.08502 0.04993 0.00540 0.01754 0.06883
R 0.04457 0.34496 0.03876 0.03101 0.00775 0.04845 0.05233 0.03295 0.02326 0.02326 0.04651 0.12016 0.01550 0.01744 0.01938 0.04457 0.03488 0.00581 0.01744 0.03101
N 0.04270 0.04494 0.31685 0.08315 0.00899 0.03371 0.04944 0.06517 0.03146 0.02247 0.03146 0.05393 0.01124 0.01798 0.02022 0.06966 0.04944 0.00449 0.01573 0.02697
D 0.04104 0.02985 0.06903 0.39739 0.00746 0.02985 0.09142 0.04664 0.01866 0.02239 0.02799 0.04478 0.00933 0.01493 0.02239 0.05224 0.03545 0.00373 0.01119 0.02425
C 0.06504 0.01626 0.01626 0.01626 0.48374 0.01220 0.01626 0.03252 0.00813 0.04472 0.06504 0.02033 0.01626 0.02033 0.01626 0.04065 0.03659 0.00407 0.01220 0.05691
Q 0.05588 0.07353 0.04412 0.04706 0.00882 0.21471 0.10294 0.04118 0.02941 0.02647 0.04706 0.09118 0.02059 0.01471 0.02353 0.05588 0.04118 0.00588 0.02059 0.03529
E 0.05525 0.04972 0.04052 0.09024 0.00737 0.06446 0.29650 0.03499 0.02578 0.02210 0.03683 0.07551 0.01289 0.01657 0.02578 0.05525 0.03683 0.00552 0.01657 0.03131
G 0.07827 0.02294 0.03914 0.03374 0.01080 0.01889 0.02564 0.51012 0.01350 0.01889 0.02834 0.03374 0.00945 0.01619 0.01889 0.05128 0.02969 0.00540 0.01080 0.02429
H 0.04198 0.04580 0.05344 0.03817 0.00763 0.03817 0.05344 0.03817 0.35496 0.02290 0.03817 0.04580 0.01527 0.03053 0.01908 0.04198 0.02672 0.00763 0.05725 0.02290
I 0.04713 0.01767 0.01473 0.01767 0.01620 0.01325 0.01767 0.02062 0.00884 0.27099 0.16789 0.02356 0.03682 0.04418 0.01473 0.02504 0.03976 0.00589 0.02062 0.17673
L 0.04453 0.02429 0.01417 0.01518 0.01619 0.01619 0.02024 0.02126 0.01012 0.11538 0.37551 0.02530 0.04960 0.05466 0.01417 0.02429 0.03340 0.00709 0.02227 0.09615
K 0.05699 0.10708 0.04145 0.04145 0.00864 0.05354 0.07081 0.04318 0.02073 0.02763 0.04318 0.27807 0.01554 0.01554 0.02763 0.05354 0.03972 0.00518 0.01727 0.03282
M 0.05221 0.03213 0.02008 0.02008 0.01606 0.02811 0.02811 0.02811 0.01606 0.10040 0.19679 0.03614 0.16064 0.04819 0.01606 0.03614 0.04016 0.00803 0.02410 0.09237
F 0.03383 0.01903 0.01691 0.01691 0.01057 0.01057 0.01903 0.02537 0.01691 0.06342 0.11416 0.01903 0.02537 0.38689 0.01057 0.02537 0.02537 0.01691 0.08879 0.05497
P 0.05685 0.02584 0.02326 0.03101 0.01034 0.02067 0.03618 0.03618 0.01292 0.02584 0.03618 0.04134 0.01034 0.01292 0.49354 0.04393 0.03618 0.00258 0.01292 0.03101
S 0.10995 0.04014 0.05410 0.04887 0.01745 0.03316 0.05236 0.06632 0.01920 0.02967 0.04188 0.05410 0.01571 0.02094 0.02967 0.21990 0.08202 0.00524 0.01745 0.04188
T 0.07298 0.03550 0.04339 0.03748 0.01775 0.02761 0.03945 0.04339 0.01381 0.05325 0.06509 0.04536 0.01972 0.02367 0.02761 0.09270 0.24655 0.00592 0.01775 0.07101
W 0.03030 0.02273 0.01515 0.01515 0.00758 0.01515 0.02273 0.03030 0.01515 0.03030 0.05303 0.02273 0.01515 0.06061 0.00758 0.02273 0.02273 0.49242 0.06818 0.03030
Y 0.04050 0.02804 0.02181 0.01869 0.00935 0.02181 0.02804 0.02492 0.04673 0.04361 0.06854 0.03115 0.01869 0.13084 0.01558 0.03115 0.02804 0.02804 0.31776 0.04673
V 0.06996 0.02195 0.01646 0.01783 0.01920 0.01646 0.02332 0.02469 0.00823 0.16461 0.13032 0.02606 0.03155 0.03567 0.01646 0.03292 0.04938 0.00549 0.02058 0.26886

**Resulting output for first sequence (KIFREIIHL):**

0,05699 0,10708 0,04145 0,04145 0,00864 0,05354 0,07081 0,04318 0,02073 0,02763 0,04318 0,27807 0,01554 0,01554 0,02763 0,05354 0,03972 0,00518 0,01727 0,03282 0,04713 0,01767 0,01473 0,01767 0,0162  0,01325 0,01767 0,02062 0,00884 0,27099 0,16789 0,02356 0,03682 0,04418 0,01473 0,02504 0,03976 0,00589 0,02062 0,17673 0,03383 0,01903 0,01691 0,01691 0,01057 0,01057 0,01903 0,02537 0,01691 0,06342 0,11416 0,01903 0,02537 0,38689 0,01057 0,02537 0,02537 0,01691 0,08879 0,05497 0,04457 0,34496 0,03876 0,03101 0,00775 0,04845 0,05233 0,03295 0,02326 0,02326 0,04651 0,12016 0,0155  0,01744 0,01938 0,04457 0,03488 0,00581 0,01744 0,03101 0,05525 0,04972 0,04052 0,09024 0,00737 0,06446 0,2965  0,03499 0,02578 0,0221  0,03683 0,07551 0,01289 0,01657 0,02578 0,05525 0,03683 0,00552 0,01657 0,03131 0,04713 0,01767 0,01473 0,01767 0,0162  0,01325 0,01767 0,02062 0,00884 0,27099 0,16789 0,02356 0,03682 0,04418 0,01473 0,02504 0,03976 0,00589 0,02062 0,17673 0,04713 0,01767 0,01473 0,01767 0,0162  0,01325 0,01767 0,02062 0,00884 0,27099 0,16789 0,02356 0,03682 0,04418 0,01473 0,02504 0,03976 0,00589 0,02062 0,17673 0,04198 0,0458  0,05344 0,03817 0,00763 0,03817 0,05344 0,03817 0,35496 0,0229  0,03817 0,0458  0,01527 0,03053 0,01908 0,04198 0,02672 0,00763 0,05725 0,0229  0,04453 0,02429 0,01417 0,01518 0,01619 0,01619 0,02024 0,02126 0,01012 0,11538 0,37551 0,0253  0,0496  0,05466 0,01417 0,02429 0,0334  0,00709 0,02227 0,09615
```

How can I create a function in R that replaces each AA for the corresponding values in the matrix?

Many thanks

Comment: It's not clear how the resulting output is computed? It seems you have extracted the row for each letter in the sequence and combined them?

Comment: You are right! The output for the first sequence is the combination of the probabilities for each AA in the sequence (comming from the matrix). Each orginal sequence has 9 AA, therefore for each sequence the output should have a length of 180 (9*20). Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `sequences` is the vector and `blosum_matrix` the name of the matrix:

```
# split each sequence to individual letters
sequences_split <- strsplit(sequences, "")

# initialise list to hold all blosum values
blo_values <- vector("list", length(sequences))

for(i in seq_along(sequences_split)){
    blo_value[[i]] <- unlist(lapply(sequences_split[[i]], function(x) blosum_matrix[x, ]))
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I tried the function you wrote, but I'm getting a list of NULL. The final output needs to be a matrix of 180 values * number of sequences. There should be 20 values per each AA and each sequences has 9 AA.

Comment: I believe the issue was that I had written "x" in the function instead of x, so it was searching for the row with name "x".